# Elixir Background Running Process

Tags: elixir

I am running a job using spawn in elixir,

```
def start_link(arg) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, arg)
  end

def init(arg) do
    pid = spawn(fn -> connect() end)
    Process.monitor(pid)
    {:ok, arg}
  end

def connect() do
    case :gen_tcp.connect(@server_ip, @port, [:binary, {:active, false}]) do
      {:ok, tcp_socket} ->
        _output = :gen_tcp.send(tcp_socket, "S,SET PROTOCOL,6.2\r\n")
        _output = :gen_tcp.send(tcp_socket, "S,NEWSON\r\n")
        receive_news_feed_helper(tcp_socket)
        :gen_tcp.close(tcp_socket)

      {:error, _reason} ->
        connect()
    end
  end
```

this process dies whenever there is any error in my terminal.

I want to always keep this process running or need to restart whenever it dies.

I'm getting news messages from a specific address. That's why started this process using spawn but this process send me response like this:

`[error] Process #PID<0.401.0> raised an exception`

How could i deal this.

Comment: You should now accept (or comment) one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should start a [`Supervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html) with your process as a child. The documentation I linked is full of ready-to-copy-paste examples.

Comment: This is the way. When you look at this documentation, search for the word "restart" to find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the existing answers, you may also simply call `connect` recursively when you're done with one client. See for instance the [Drink DNS server](https://framagit.org/bortzmeyer/drink) to see how to do it (in `lib/drink/server.ex`, see the [tcp_loop_acceptor function](https://framagit.org/bortzmeyer/drink/-/blob/master/lib/drink/server.ex?ref_type=heads#L204)).

Answer (score 0):

When I have written Elixir code that needs to handle TCP connections, I've generally written a GenServer not too different than what you've done, but with `handle_continue` for simple state transitions, or the old [Connection](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/connection) module from the Ecto folks (now deprecated), or [:gen_statem](https://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/statem), but I directly invoke the `:tcp` module functions rather than spawning them. There may have been one or two exceptions where I used Process.monitor as you have done (I think I did something like that once when I wrote something in Membrane Framework that has its own process abstraction), but if you do that, you need to have handle_info handlers for the `{:DOWN, ref, :process, object, reason}` messages you'll receive, and decide how to handle them (i.e. restart the connection, backoff, etc).

For most cases, though, direct tcp calls from the GenServer or :gen_statem module are less complicated than spawning an additional process for just the tcp conversations; I'd put my connection model under a supervising process, typically [Supervisor](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15.6/Supervisor.html) if my application can know at the time the supervisor is started which child processes to create, or [DynamicSupervisor](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.15.6/DynamicSupervisor.html) if I need some other process to spin up and down connections.